# Confused - How to get the geocode for an address (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, maps

I create a small web app, the user add his address and I want to show the map for his address.
Is there a way to get the `latitude` and `longitude` for an address? with Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the geocoding service from google maps: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Here's a simple example for it: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

Comment: Thank you, But i want to use this option without putting the address and click and gecoding button, I should give the address (because I get it from my mysql table)

Comment: you can do that too, read the address using php and then call the javascript function to geocode it.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know how

Comment: Here's a tutorial I wrote: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/interactive-travel-map-google-maps-api/. It's much more than you need, you just need the part for reading the data from the db, and before showing the points on the map, you'll need to add the javascript function to geocode the address. you could email me if you have any other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It is called geocoding. Here is Google's API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/